# How to sort custom columns in GridView widget in Yii 2?

Tags: php, yii, yii2

I have a custom column in  GridView. Actually it's model attribute but I needed  to customize it for presenting data in more convenience way. How to add an ability to sort this column?

```
<?= GridView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'filterPosition'=>  GridView::FILTER_POS_HEADER,
    'columns' => [
        ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],

        'id',
        'username',
        'about:ntext',
         'birthdate',
        ['attribute'=>'sex',
         'header'=>'Sex',
         'content'=>  function($model){
          return $model->sex==0?'female':'male';  
         },
         'label'=>'Sex',
         'enableSorting'=>TRUE       

        ],

         'email:email',

        ['class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn'],
    ],
]); ?>
```

Comment: The problem is: you always sort data on database side. Please provide more information (source code) about that custom column/attribute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You lost your sort link because you are explicitly set `'header'=>'Sex'` in your column configuration, remove it and sort link should appear.

Comment: thanks, man. By some reason, I thought that it it's mandatory to set header.

Answer (score 0):

I'll assume you're using `ActiveDataProvider`.

Even when you use a custom function to display the attribute, the sorting is done on the actual attribute that is stored in the DB.

Try generating a set of CRUD pages using `gii`. If you did everything right, your `index.php` file in `views` will contain an array of columns. Then you can configure your column like so:

```
        [
            'attribute' => 'myAttribute',
            'value' => function ($data) {
                return 'example'.' '.$data->myAttribute;
            }
        ],
```

Obviously, the function needs to do whatever transformations you need. But the sorting will be done on the actual data stored in the DB.

Comment: Yes, I'm using ActiveDataProvider and crud pages I generated crud pages by gii. But after customization of column the sort link in header lost, I just want this sorting link in header cell back. I added code of widget to question.

Answer (score 0):

For searching sex it's easy you can set filter. Like

```
   [
    'attribute'=> 'sex',
    # if you didn't set attribute in model or want different text use label
   'label' => 'Sex of person',
    # if you create it threw ModelSearch and there is attribute/field in one table gii will add automatically andFilterWhere method.
    'filter' => ['0' => 'Female', '1' => 'Male'],
   ],
```

For more complicated search/sort here is very good documentation related [link to tutorial](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/621/filter-sort-by-calculated-related-fields-in-gridview-yii-2-0/)