# yii2 GridView sort on column click

Tags: gridview, yii2

I learn yii2, tried to make GridView::widget with sortable date column.

I found an easy way, use: `'columns' => ['created_at:datetime']` but I don't understand how to make the same with custom way.

Here is my code:

```
<?=GridView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'columns' => 
    [
        ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],
        'created_at:datetime',      //an easy way, makes default asc/desc sort on link click

        [
            'header' => "Date",     //the same, but how to make sort, (need to add link someway)?
            'format' => 'datetime',
            'value' => 'created_at',
            'contentOptions'=>['style'=>'width: 130px;',
                'enableSorting' => true,
            ]
        ],
    ],
    'options' => ['class'=>'doc-table'],


]);
?>
```

Here is `$dataProvider`:

```
        $dataProvider->sort = ['defaultOrder' =>
                        //['created_at' => 'desc'],
                        ['attributes' => 
                            ['created_at' =>
                                [
                                    'asc' => ['created_at' => SORT_ASC],
                                    'desc' => ['created_at' => SORT_DESC],
                                ]
                            ]
                        ],
                    ];  
    return $this->render('index', [
                'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    ]);
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to sort custom columns in GridView widget in Yii 2?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30956638/how-to-sort-custom-columns-in-gridview-widget-in-yii-2)

Answer (score 1):

You use attribute name On field of 'created_at'.

Like..

```
[
'attribute' => 'created_at',
'header' => 'date',
'Value' => .....,
]
```